# Create attachment from the stream of the data

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am trying to create SendGrid email attachment on-the-fly in C# on Azure. How can I correct the following code where `someString` is a variable holding the attachment xml content as directly retrieved from the DB?

```
using (var attachmentFileStream = new FileStream(@someString, FileMode.Open))
{
    message.AddAttachment(attachmentFileStream, "someattachmentname.xml");
}
```

It does not seem to like it. I am getting the following errors:

- Illegal characters in path. Access to the path
- 'D:\Windows\system32-1' is denied.

Comment: What is the type of `message`?

Comment: var message = new SendGridMessage();

Comment: Hm. What is inside `someString` then?

Comment: a character string converted into MemoryStream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... i think I figured it out. When I pass the stream type into the method I need to strip the "using (var attachmentFileStream..." wrap and pass it directly into the **myMessage.AddAttachment** i.e.:

```
// convert to Stream type not MemoryStream!
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString);

Stream theStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

myMessage.AddAttachment(theStream, "someattachmentname.xml");
```